# C# Chart ArguementOutOfRangeExecption

Tags: c#, charts

I have the following `abstract` class:

```
    public abstract class ChartHelper
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart resultChart { get; set; }
    public String TimeType { get; set; }
    protected  List<IObject> _datalist;
    protected  TimeType _timeType;
    protected  DateTime _stopDate;
    protected  DateTime _startDate;


    protected void SetXAsisTime()
    {
        if (resultChart != null)
        {
            foreach (var series in resultChart.Series)
            {
                series.XValueType = _timeType != DateUtils.TimeType.Weeks ? ChartValueType.DateTime : ChartValueType.String;
            }
            resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = GetLabelFormat();
            resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = GetIntervalType();
            resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
        }
    }

    protected String GetLabelFormat()
    {
        switch (_timeType)
        {
            case DateUtils.TimeType.Weeks:
                return "Uge:";
            case DateUtils.TimeType.Months:
                return "MM";
            case DateUtils.TimeType.Years:
                return "YYYY";
            default:
                return "DD";
        }
    }
```

Now when i attempt to set  the AxisX label format : `resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = GetLabelFormat();`

I get the following error message:

```
  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at Henvendelser.Chart.ChartHelper.SetXAsisTime()
       at Henvendelser.Chart.EmailChartGenerator.GetChart()
       at Henvendelser.Models.EmailModel.GetEmailChart(DateTime start, DateTime end, TimeType timeType)
       at Henvendelser.Main.SetHenvendelserData(DateTime from, DateTime to)
       at Henvendelser.Main.btn_getData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Henvendelser.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Can someone tell me what i am missing? or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChartAreas` Collection is still empty (`Count == 0`). That's why you cannot access the item at index `0`. Which leads to your `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: what is ChartAreas? and are they required for the chart to be displayed? i'm sorry but i am quite new to charting in C#

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I guess you need to initialize the ChartAreas prior using them: `resultChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX`. I also have no idea about Microsoft charting - sorry on that.

Comment: `ChartAreas` are the pieces of the `Chart` object which contain axes, display data points, etc. They are a collection, so you need to add at least one `ChartArea` element. This can be done in the designer in Visual Studio or programmatically. I suggest you take a look at the tutorials and such on MSDN, as they provide quite a bit of information to get started with charts in C#.